# NSBlockOperation is not waiting on dependency before executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsblockoperation

I am learning `NSOperations` & `NSOperationQueue`.

I have a set of `NSBlockOperation`: "*UPLOAD*" & "*DELETE*". Delete ***MUST***  wait for Upload to finish before executing.

What I would like to happen is for one operation set to complete before moving on to the next set.

I have used `NSThread sleepForTimeInterval` to simulate the upload waiting and deletion latency times.

However the operations are not waiting for the set to complete.

I set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1 but that doesn't seem to work.

You can see from the output that Set 1 finished fine.

But in set two ***Upload 3*** stared before the ***Delete 2*** was finished. Then Upload/Delete 4 is fine. Then from there it starts to mix up a lot more.

***Any help?***

**OUTPUT:**

```
Start UPLOAD 1
Completed UPLOAD 1
Start DELETE 1
Completed DELETE 1

Start UPLOAD 2
Completed UPLOAD 2
Start DELETE 2
Start UPLOAD 3
Completed DELETE 2
Start DELETE 3
Completed UPLOAD 3
Completed DELETE 3

Start UPLOAD 4
Start DELETE 4
Completed UPLOAD 4
Completed DELETE 4

Start UPLOAD 5
Start DELETE 5
Completed UPLOAD 5
Start UPLOAD 6
Completed DELETE 5
Start DELETE 6
Completed UPLOAD 6
Start UPLOAD 7
Completed DELETE 6
```

**CODE:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;


//pretend there are 100 images that need to be uploaded and information in a SQLite DB waiting to be deleted upon successful upload of the image.

//Upload 1 image at a time, upon successful upload, delete the respective DB info then move to the next image 
    for (__block int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        NSOperation * UPLOAD = [self createNewOperationWithInt:i Message:@"UPLOAD"];
        NSOperation * DELETE = [self createNewOperationWithInt:i Message:@"DELETE"];
        [DELETE addDependency:UPLOAD];
        [operationQueue addOperation:UPLOAD];
        [operationQueue addOperation:DELETE];

    }

}

- (NSBlockOperation *) createNewOperationWithInt:(int)i Message:(NSString*)message {
    NSBlockOperation * operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Start %@ %i",message , i);

        if ([message containsString:@"UPLOAD"]) {
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //Pretend there is Network latency on upload
        }

        if ([message containsString:@"DELETE"]) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5]; //Pretend the SQLDB is being accessed
        }

    }];
    operation.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal;
    operation.qualityOfService  = NSOperationQualityOfServiceUtility;
    operation.completionBlock = ^{
       NSLog(@"Completed %@ %i",message , i);
    };

    return operation;
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation for the `completionBlock` property of `NSOperation`. That discussion explains your output.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior seems to be fine. The "problem" is that both the completion block and the dependency run after the completion of the *upload* task. That's why you sometimes get the "Start DELETE N+1" before the "Completed UPLOAD N".

Try adding a message at the end of the block operation, to check that it finishes before starting the next one:

```
NSBlockOperation * operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Start %@ %i",message , i);

    if ([message containsString:@"UPLOAD"]) {
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //Pretend there is Network latency on upload
    }

    if ([message containsString:@"DELETE"]) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5]; //Pretend the SQLDB is being accessed
    }

    NSLog(@"Finished %@ %i",message , i);
}];
```